# JQM rewind history back more than one step

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have the following visual activities:

1. List of issues.
2. Detailed card of issue.
3. Popup to confirm deletion of issue.

Last one is interesting widget:

- when I press "No" (don't want to delete), then I need to return back to detailed card. Implementation is simple - just add `data-rel="back"` to button link.
- when I press "Yes" (yes, want to delete issue), then after deletion I need to return back TWICE to list of issues - because deleted issue already not exist.

How to implement last bullet? Guess no need to point direct page url (yes, it's possible, but not flexible).

Comment: Manipulate pages dynamically using `$.mobile.changePage()`. Using `data-rel=back` will limit control over your pages. Combining it with `.on()` callback events.

Answer (score 2):

To go back two steps (second previous page) using `.prevAll()` as follows.

```
var previous = '#' + $.mobile.activePage.prevAll('[data-role=page]')[1].id;
$.mobile.changePage(previous, { transition: 'flip', reverse: true });
```

where `[1]` is the index of second previous page in `[object]` of previous pages.

To use this method, your pages should have `id`.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/p4zAz/)**

Comment: Omar, thanks.
Good idea.
Being precise:
var previous = $('#' + $.mobile.activePage.prevAll('[data-role=page]'))[0].id;

Comment: @ValeryBulash `[0]` will take you to first previous page as you're using data-rel=back.

Comment: Meaning popup is no page but div inside page - first previous page is what I want.
Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I have checked this recipe again:

- yes, it is change page to what I want.
- no, it's not rewind a history.

What I mean as "rewind":

History of steps: page0 - page1 - page2 - "confirm deletion".
What I expect - "confirm deletion" change page to page1. Press then back - page changed to page0.

What I see - "confirm deletion" change page to page1 (right). Press then back - page changed to page2 (wrong!). It's normal behaviour when changing page, but not in my case.

How to **REWIND**?